# Create multiple Firebase streams with custom model/class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a MultiProvider in my main function.

I'd like to implement a second stream for different collection in firebase. Multiprovider in main:

```
StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>(
   create: (_) => getWeeksStreamSnapshot(_), //collection weeks
),
StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>(
   create: (_) => getMessagesStreamSnapshot(_), //collection messages
),
```

But now I get an **error because both streams have type QuerySnapshot**.

I'm looking for something like this with a custom class:

```
StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>(
       create: (_) => getWeeksStreamSnapshot(_), //collection weeks
    ),
    StreamProvider<MYCLASS>(
       create: (_) => getMessagesStreamSnapshot(_), //collection messages
    ),
```

I tried this:

```
Stream<MYCLASS> getMessagesStreamSnapshot(BuildContext context) async* {
    try {
      final auth = Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context, listen: false);
      final uid = await auth.getFormattedUID();
      print("Getting messages as stream in main...");

       MYCLASS(
          snapshot: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(uid)
              .collection('chat')
              .snapshots()); //This is the error because .snapshots() is a stream
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

with this class:

```
class MYCLASS {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot;
  MYCLASS({this.snapshot});
}
```

How can I make the MYCLASS class return a QuerySnapshot, so it's clear when I access the
`Provider.of<MYCLASS>(context)`

Firebase looks like this:

[image]

So the **document I am looking for is called messages** (inside the chat collection).

Comment: Why don't you just return the ```FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('chat').snapshots();```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
getMessagesStreamSnapshot() async* {
  var querySnapshot;
  const sec = Duration(seconds: 1);
Timer.periodic(sec, (Timer t) async {
  querySnapshot =  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('chat')
        .get();
  });

  yield  { 'snapshot':querySnapshot,'type':'message'};
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks first of all. Now when I do this and then print the output of that it returns " flutter: {snapshot: Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot>', type: message}"

Comment: @Finn What do you want to do with it? Do you want to push it into a stream builder?

Comment: So because I am already accessing firebase with a stream that returns a QuerySnapshot, I now want to find a way to access a second collection in firebase with a second stream.

Comment: Because if I have two streams, that access two different collections and they both return a QuerySnapshot, I get an error (The Provider can't differentiate between the two QuerySnapshots)

Comment: I think I understand your answer. When we do yield* instead of yield, we could access the Stream result (So the QuerySnapshot) and not the stream itself. But this doesn't work when I try it with your code. Is there a workaround for this, so I can use the Provider and do something like this: QuerySnapshot snapshot = data['snapshot'];

Comment: @Finn Could you add the error that shows the code does not work?

Comment: Your code is working I think. But it does not solve my problem completely unfortunately. So I think the problem is this yield / yield* operator. Because the yield* enables us to get the QuerySnapshot. And the yield only returns the stream. I would like to use the yield* to access the QuerySnapshot directly. I updated my first post.

Comment: @Finn check this

Comment: Nice approach, but I think I would be charged for every single read then. Because it reads the database every second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247561/discussion-between-georgina-and-finn).